# Will the job of Data Science is going to be at risk?

Tags: machine-learning, ai, research

Data Science is the sexiest job of 21st Century according to the different sources with a high payment salary . But it seems that there will be over production of this profession . According to U.S. Bureau of Labor Statistics there will be about 11.6 million jobs in 2026 but looking at the current trend there may be over production of data science professional till 2026 which may cause unemployment of Data science professionals .

According to a research , the data science syllabus is harder than non Data Science syllabus in engineering.

The skills required for a Data Scientist are:

- Computer Science Skill
- Mathematics (Calculus , Linear Algebra , Statistics and Probability , Optimization , Numerical Analysis , etc)
- Domain Specific Skills

The above 3 points looks simpler but if we start go for mastery it takes a lot of energy and time.

I am 19 year old from a undeveloped country seeking as a professional in Data science but the above mentioned statement makes me to think whether to choose a Data Science as a profession or not ? If I am wrong then it will be my pleasure to give some guidance to a 19 year old boy who completed his 10th grade and passionated in machine learning and Data Science as a profession .

Waiting for your open minded reply  and stay safe in global pandemic☺️

Comment: Its opinion-based question, more suitable on Quora, please be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

I highly doubt that the job itself will going to be at risk. It is rather the other way around: Data science and machine learning will replace a lot of other jobs. In the end there, at least, always needs to be someone providing the data to the machine. 
It seems like your question rather should be "will there be enough data science positions in the future to have good chances of getting a job". While I can not give you a concrete answer to this question, I can tell you that, I think, most other jobs have a way higher risk. Data science or, maybe, even more machine learning, seems like a good and future-proof choice for me.